# ICS without the default DHCP server

Tags: windows, windows-7, dhcp, internet

Using windows 7, Is it possible to turn on Internet Connection Sharing but rather than using the built in dhcp provided by windows, I want to use my own app to handle that. Is there a way to turn off the provided dhcp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following provides some notes on the subject - http://www.lanpartynw.com/forumse/index.php?topic=369.0.

There doesn't seem to be any information on disabling DHCP with ICS. Another approach which is just as effective will be to utilize a managed switch with DHCP Snooping capabilities. The valid DHCP server(s) can then be identified while ignoring all other unauthorized ones.

Comment: Here are a few more approaches - http://www.zimbio.com/Windows+XP/articles/wpdWfNbATpq/Windows+Server+2008+Disable+DHCP+ICS.